# Hello, I don't know why I still can't load assets after writing the path of the assets[already answered,]

Tags: flutter, assets

Please see the attached pictures for my code and error messages. Thank you very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqtyI.png)

Comment: Did you run pub get?

Comment: Yes!..............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assets: needs to be in flutter: So you didn't tab enough for your assets:
Your pubspec.yaml should look like this

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/OptimizeYourFood/
```